# Does CMake allow setting the location of external source files for Visual Studio projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

My project uses Qt as external library and whenever I want to debug into Qt I have to specify the location of the source files. After re-generating the project this information is lost and I have to set the location again.

Visual Studio allows under the Solution properties to specify pathes at which it will look for source files during debugging. So the question is, if CMake provides a way to set these pathes. If that was possible, I could set them once in the cmake code and remove the annoyance of re-specifying them all the time.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: ***whenever I want to debug into Qt I have to specify the location of the source files*** It does not do this for me with Visual Studio. However I build Qt from source and use find_package() to pull in Qt.

Comment: I believe your settings could be placed in a `.user` file in the same folder that the project file is generated.

Comment: @drescherjm 1. I think when you consume a Qt that you have built locally, the pathes in the pdb files to the source files are correct. In my case Qt is build somewhere else and so the pdb files contain the wrong pathes from the build machine. 2. I will look into your suggestion with the .user file. This may at least help to implement a workaround. Although I would prefer a solution that is delivered by cmake ;-)